# expand all view when activity is load in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

My problem is...
I use Expandable list view in my activity.
When the activity created it shows all the child group is collapsed. 
I would like to expand all children while the expandable list view is populated.
like

for that, I used below code in `getGroupView()` method adapter class

```
ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) parent         
eLV.expandGroup(groupPosition,true);
```

now the groups are expanded but it can not allow me to collapse by clicking on the group header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `groupClickListener` and `return true` for disabling collapse the child list. Add this code to your activity.

```
yourExpandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                              int groupPosition, long id) { 
    return true; // This way the expander cannot be collapsed
  }
});
```